# Textbox Shows before Label Text

Tags: html

Not sure why the textbox shows first an then my text which I'm not using a real label tag shows up AFTER the textbox

```
<p>Token: <input type="text" id="txt_Token" /></p>
```

[ textbox ] Token:

Comment: Maybe you have a CSS float occuring?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tULEW/  its working , check your css

Comment: Your code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are floating your `input` element left:

```
#txt_Token{
    float:left;
}
```

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5cWC/)